# パスワードが正しくありません、はまずくないっすか？

Tags: 機能の要求

私は stackexchange を使用してログインを使っています。
メールアドレス部分を正しく入力し、試験的にパスワードを誤って入力すると
「パスワードが正しくありません」と出ます。

同様、メールアドレス部分を試験的に故意に誤って入力すると
「メールアドレスが有効なものではありません」
「入力されたメールアドレスのアカウントが見つかりませんでした」
となる挙動を確認しました。

これは現代的セキュリティ観点的にはまずくないっすか？
個人的には「ありえない」っす。改善を要望します。

Comment: 開発者と確認中です。開発者が後日英語で説明します。その説明を翻訳させていただきます。

Comment: メタSEにも「ログイン試行は十分に監視・回数制限されていて、ブルートフォース・列挙攻撃にも効果がある」といったコメントがありますね http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239322/286934

Comment: stackexchange は stackoverflow とちがい geek 以外を主ターゲットとしている（であろう）ので、
この回答は予想したとおりですし、まあ納得もできるのですが
本当は stackexchange (なり stackoverflow なり) には他のサイト（ログイン機能があるサイト）へのセキュリティ面でのお手本となってほしかったのです。
stackexchange がこういう運用をしているから、ウチもこうしよう！
という安易な運用をするサイトが増えてほしくないのです。

Comment: @774RR 実は、SEはSOを使っているgeekに他の趣味のあるトピックについて話せるために作っています。SOユーザーはプログラマーだけでなく、料理を作っている人もいるし、子供がいるユーザーもいるし、ゲームが趣味の方もいます。SEでも、SOでも「geek」に制限することを目指していませんが、SOが一番大きなため、geekの密度が高いですね。

Comment: 関連 http://security.stackexchange.com/q/62661

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was definitely something we thought about when designing the login/signup pages.

We decided that giving users something direct (i.e. problem with username vs password) was better for user experience. Helping people log in when they are trying to log in, instead of giving a vague message ("something is wrong").

---

この課題を十分考えた上でログイン・サインアップページを作成しました。

ユーザーに直接問題のヒント（問題はメール関連かパスワード関連か）を与えることで、ユーザーにより使いやすくできると思っていました。不明な「問題ある」メッセージより、ログインを助けることができるメッセージの方がいいと決めました。

Comment: それがSE/SOの方針であるということなら１ユーザである私が何か言うことはありません。現代的セキュリティ面としては SE/SO をお手本にしてはならない、ということだけ追記した上で回答としてマークさせていただきます。

Answer (score 9):

**現代的**セキュリティ観点から言えばもはやさほど問題では無いと考えます。

かつてこれが問題だと言われていたのは、

- (ブルートフォース)攻撃の際のヒントとなる
- IDリスティングに使われる

のが理由です。

古典的ブルートフォース攻撃に関して言えば、アカウントロックで対抗します。

IDリスティングについては、同一IPアドレスからのログイン試行をブロックする対策が行われていれば、分散型の攻撃以外は防げます。そもそも、メールアドレスをIDに使っている場合、IDリスティングはさほど問題ではありません。利用者としてIDリスティングが致命的な問題だと考えるのであれば、サードパーティアカウントによる認証も用意されているので利用者が回避できるでしょう。

なお、現在では認証を突破する攻撃の手法はリバースブルートフォースであるとかリスト攻撃とかジョーアカウント攻撃とか、「既知のID候補」を利用するのが主流で、これらに対してはログイン画面でIDの存在がヒントとして提示されても大きな問題にはなりません。これらの攻撃に対しては、先に書いた同一IPアドレスからのログイン試行をブロックする対策で(ある程度)対策します。(正しくはこっちが先で、IDリスティングの緩和は付随的効果)

ということで、ログイン試行に対する対策が行われているのであれば、現状のメッセージでも攻撃に対して脆弱ということにはなりません。対策が行われていないのであればそのこと自体が問題ですので、メッセージがなんであるかは些末な問題ということになります。

Answer (score 1):

なぜかアカウント復元メールの方はメールアドレスが間違っていても教えてくれません。

[image: スクリーンショット]